# Select query using IN() and without any sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

My query

```
select * from product where productId in(25,36,40,1,50);
```

Result shows as follows

```
`productId   ProductName  Qty Price`
-------------------------------------
`1          | namesome  | 5 | 25.00`
`25         | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
`36         | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
`40         | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
`50         | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
```

I did not use any `order by` clause, But its automatically applied order by `productId`,
I need result with out any sort, as follows

```
`productId   ProductName  Qty Price`
-------------------------------------
`25        | namesome  | 5 | 25.00`
`36        | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
`40        | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
`1         | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
`50        | namesome  | 5 | 35.00`
```

How can I achieve this?
Database Engine: MyIsam, Collation: utf8_general_ci, PrimaryKey on `productId`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select * 
from product 
where productId in(25,36,40,1,50) 
order by find_in_set(productId, '25,36,40,1,50');
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c41d4/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be randomly ordered, do:

```
select * from product where productId in(25,36,40,1,50) ORDER BY RAND()
```

The default ordering is probably due to the way the IDs are sorted in the index.

Comment: The OP wants in this order `(25,36,40,1,50)`

Comment: @hims056 I thought that was just an example.