# How to retrieve items in a manually-specified order

Tags: mysql

I have a list of id's in PHP. For example:

```
$id = (4,6,3,2,5,1)
```

When I perform a query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ($id)");
```

it retrieves the results I want but the items are returned in the insertion order.

Instead, I want to retrieve the results in the order given in my array:

```
information 4, information 6, information 3, information 2, information 5, information 1
```

How can I do that?

Thanks guys! solution is ORDER BY FIELD (ID, $id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ($id) ORDER BY FIELD(ID,$id) ";
```

you can see this http://marco-pivetta.com/mysql-custom-sorting-rule-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ($id) ORDER BY ";

foreach ($id as $i) {
   $query .= "ID = $i,";
}
$query = mysql_query(rtrim($query, ','));
```

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ($id) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID,$id) DESC";
```

Also check this

[Select query using IN() and without any sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657859/select-query-without-any-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIELD` on this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ID IN (4,6,3,2,5,1)
ORDER BY FIELD(ID, 4,6,3,2,5,1)
```

- [Custom Sorting using FIELD() example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD (ID,4,6,3,2,5,1) does not work. but (ID,$id) works

Comment: can you provide sample records?