# MySQL : How to display data from mysql database using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to share a image below

[image]

Actually , in my MySQL database data has like **Table 1**.

But i need to display the table like **Table 2**.

The Model Code is given below

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->form('tbl_name');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

But i know that it won't be the desired result.

Actually We don't need distinct. We need all data(Every Row) but Duplicate Date won't be together.

For Example ,

```
ID  Name   Questions

1   John   Test question1 

1   John   Test question2
```

ID can't be second row after first row.(On the other hand Two/many same row can't stay aonther row after one row.)

Please see again two table.

So, Please give me any solution.

Comment: is ID unique? Why would you use `group by`?

Comment: Still it doesn't make sense, the ID field is Auto Incremented or it is ID of user?

Comment: you may need to use **order by find_in_set**

Comment: This ID is not auto increment id but increment id has other  @Kyslik

Comment: it may useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657859/select-query-using-in-and-without-any-sorting

Comment: But ID can be more so it is difficult @user1844933

Comment: Two same ID can not be stay together @user1844933

Comment: use distinct :) am i correct?

Comment: @MD.ABDULHalim do you want to do in query itself or in php code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select only the first distinct match from a field in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010763/how-can-i-select-only-the-first-distinct-match-from-a-field-in-mysql)

Comment: Please try to understand the question , then Comment me. The Question can't duplicate which you should realize. @JackalopeZero.

Comment: Actually No, I have some edited my question please see again. @user1844933

Comment: It can be php code or mysql. Actually i need the result.Please help me. @kumar_v

Comment: you need to display ids as non-sequential. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting same IDs should not appear sequentially, then you can do order by questions.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->form('tbl_name');
$this->db->order_by("questions");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Note: Same user should not have same question twice. It's simple solution as per your requirement.

Comment: Actually i need display the table when Same ID can't stay another after one. It will maintain unique sequence. Am i Clear to you. @kumar_v

Comment: what are you getting for my answer? Is it not matching with your requirement?

Comment: No, I can't get my answer. Same ID can't stay another after one. Please read the question again and see the both table.

Comment: is there any chance of having same person having same question twice or more?

Comment: Actually The Question is Unique. Same Person can question twice or more but can't be same question.